# boto ssl_proxy error: 'str' does not support the buffer interface

Tags: django, amazon-s3, boto

This error seems to be a known issue that hasn't been made a priority (see https://github.com/boto/boto/pull/2718). I'm using the 2.39 version of boto along with `django-storages-redux` to enable S3 for my media files. Currently getting the error at `boto/connection.py in proxy_ssl, line 796`.

I've tried replacing boto with boto3, but that does not work with django-storages-redux.

Has anyone found an alternative for using S3 through an SSL proxy?

#### EDIT:

When I say boto3 does not work with django-storages, it's because of these imports in storages/backends/s3boto.py:

```
try:
    from boto import __version__ as boto_version
    from boto.s3.connection import S3Connection, SubdomainCallingFormat
    from boto.exception import S3ResponseError
    from boto.s3.key import Key as S3Key
    from boto.utils import parse_ts, ISO8601
except ImportError:
    raise ImproperlyConfigured("Could not load Boto's S3 bindings.\n"
                               "See https://github.com/boto/boto")
```

Comment: Looks like there is support from django-storages for boto3 in the works: https://github.com/jschneier/django-storages/pull/111

Comment: I had/have the same problem. I found that manually applying the fix included in the commit 8ee04fd (yet to be merged) worked for me. There's six lines of code in boto/connections.py where the strings need to be encoded.